# Hibernate search - cconvert sql to lucene query

Tags: java, sql, lucene, hibernate-search

I have the below select SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM data_entity WHERE 
agreement_number='9999' AND use_type='xxxx' AND end_date IS NOT NULL AND end_date <= '2022-05-03'::date 
OR (rib='1111111' AND iban='22222222');
```

I want to convert it to query using hibernate search, i tried with the below query, but it doesn't give me the right result, can anyone see what can be the problem with the query?

```
@Entity
@Indexed
 public class DataEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String agreementNumber;

    @Field
    private String useType;

    @Field
    @DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.DAY)
    private Date endDate;

    @Field
    private String rib;

    @Field
    private String iban;
    
}

org.apache.lucene.search.Query firstQuery = getQuery().bool()
    .must(getQuery().bool()
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("agreementNumber").matching(agreementNumber).createQuery())
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("useType").matching(useType).createQuery())
        .must(getQuery().range().onField("endDate").above(effectiveDate).createQuery()).createQuery())
    .should(getQuery().bool()
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("rib").matching(rib).createQuery())
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("iban").matching(iban).createQuery()).createQuery())
        .createQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `must` and `should` in the same boolean query. This probably won't do what you think it will.

To emulate a boolean `AND`, use a boolean query with only `must` clauses.
To emulate a boolean `OR`, use a boolean query with only `should` clauses.

Also, you're using `above` to compare the date, while your SQL query is clearly looking for dates *before* the given date.

So, try that:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query firstQuery = getQuery().bool()
    .should(getQuery().bool()
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("agreementNumber").matching(agreementNumber).createQuery())
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("useType").matching(useType).createQuery())
        .must(getQuery().range().onField("endDate").below(effectiveDate).createQuery()).createQuery())
    .should(getQuery().bool()
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("rib").matching(rib).createQuery())
        .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("iban").matching(iban).createQuery()).createQuery())
        .createQuery();
```

On a related note, you may also want to disable analysis on fields that represents codes, such as `agreementNumber`, `rib`, etc. Otherwise you may end up with more matches than you intended. Alternatively, if you need some level of leniency, but not full-blown analysis, you can rely on `normalizers`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-normalizers

(for anyone else reading this, a "RIB" is a French bank account identifier, not a chunk of meat)